# Pass address from one Vc to another

Tags: swift, mapkit, pass-data

I'm trying to pass the address I get from the map into my other Viewcontroller and keep the same settings (i.e switch is still on) [image: what I'm trying to do] The mapVC is named `MapViewController` and the tableVC is named `AddTaskTableViewController`.

Comment: First, establish whether you are using navigationController or segues?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you need to pass the data in `prepareForSegue` method, like this in your MapViewController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? AddTaskTableViewController{
        destinationViewController.address = self.address// Get address from map and stored here
    }
}
```

For your second question about setting, you need to save setting into UseDefaults and whenever your view controller is loaded, set value from UserDefault. Here are example code

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("address", forKey: "address")

UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "address")
```

Comment: Hey I'm trying to get the segue to work I've added the function to my mapVC but it don't seem to pass the value to the addTaskVC ideas?